# Embed iframe when inserting a post

Tags: feature, ribbon, html-editor, iframe

I developed a Ribbon button that show's up in the Media tab. This displays a Modal Dialog to the user, listing some external content, and when clicking on an item it pastes the iframe html code on the post editor. The iframe actually is rendered when I'm adding the post but when I save it just disappears. So It's being removed by SharePoint.

I've checked a couple of solutions, but most of them require to include some javascript code in the master page to prevent from this iframe code to be destroyed by SharePoint.

Is there any other solution that could go side by side with my Ribbon Control Project? I mean without changing the master page. I've done a "filter" when developing for moodle, so instead of one plugin, I had two ( plugin itself and the filter required to display an iframe )..I could do the same here, but what kind of project will I need to create to "filter" the content?